# RecyclerView and Adapter, which one should take care of Data Change?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

In RecyclerViewFragment Class, there is MovieData, and the Adapter Class stores MovieData.getMovieList( ).

My question is, when Event Handler be triggered,

1. Add / Delete data directly in RecyclerViewFragment Class
2. Define add( ) / delete( ) function in Adapter Class and call adapter.add( ) / adapter.delete( ) in RecyclerViewFragment Class

Which way is the better design? Who has the responsibility to take care of data change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to have RecyclerViewFragment containing the data. And create an adapter passing the reference to the data. For example:

```
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mMovieData.getMovieList());
```

Then in the RecyclerViewFragment just perform the needed actions such as add / remove such as:

```
mMovieData.getMovieList().add(index);
```

Think this is the most common way todo it. You do not want to replicate the getMovieList data twice in adapter and RecyclerViewFragment. This will get confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Really looks cleaner to code in this way

Answer (score 0):

If data change is happening after adapter has been initialized, then it should be handled inside adapter. Adapter also has a nifty function `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will update item positions inside the adapter when data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The recyclerview is not concerned with the data, this is all handled by the adapter you have created to present the data. Have a look at the functions [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) to see what options you have in regard to data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter is the responsible class for filling a list with data ,for example if you have a list that need to be filled with data lets say SCORES then the adapter is the one responsible for filling these scores in the list. on the other side, RecyclerView is reposnsilbe for making the adapter fill it with more speed and effecieny, the recyclerView uses views that are previously used to display data by the adapter and place them in cache for later reuse to display the same type object so that it doesn't have to initialize a new object each time the adapter want to fill item in the list which make it faster.

[and here is a link that might help you as well :](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Hope my answer have helped you.

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't describe my question clearly. I'm not saying who should inflate the View with existing data. I'm saying, for example, if I long click one ItemView, that data will be cloned in dataSet, then call notifyDataSetChanged(). So who should do the clone job?  RecyclerView or Adapter?